# iOS webview video URL in lock screen

Tags: ios, webview, wkwebview

I have an app which includes a webview (loading content served by a local HTTP server) that has an mp4 video embedded, and if I lock the screen while playing the video it will show the URL on the lock screen as seen in the attached screenshot.

Is it possible to replace the URL that is displayed with a custom string / video title?

Perhaps a custom header in the request's response or something similar?

[image: lock screen with video URL]

Comment: I don't know, but since you didn't mentioned it for your researches, you may want to look for `MPNow​Playing​Info​Center`.

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up finding a solution which only requires adding an attribute to the video tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Is it possible to change the iOS 8 lock screen audio label when playing from web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303376/is-it-possible-to-change-the-ios-8-lock-screen-audio-label-when-playing-from-web)

Just use the `title` attribute in the `<video>` tag.