# how to give a image to the system audio or video player in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When I watch videos on YouTube such as pewdiepie and that time I adjust the audio. And that time it shows the thumbnail of the video like below

[image: The Image When It Shows in the system during watching YouTube]

It Also Shows A Image In Shortcut Player On Chrome

[image: Shortcut player in Chrome]

But I also want to make a player and give a thumbnail like the above images.
I tried this

```
<video src="..." poster="./example.png">
</video>
/* 
Who Don't knows about it
link to know more about the poster attribute:- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp#:~:text=The%20poster%20attribute%20specifies%20an,video%20will%20be%20used%20instead.
*/
```

And Also Tried This

```
<video src="...">
<img src="./example.jpg"/>
</video>
```

But It Also Didn't work
I search almost everywhere for the answer
But It Gives A Result Like This:
In the system player (windows)

[image: system player result for my code]

In the shortcut player (chrome)

[image: shortcut player result for my code]

If My codes not working then how is YouTube giving a thumbnail and also a subtitle(in the there is the title and bottom of that it is written PewDiePie)

Comment: Btw here is an older answer to your question from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418606/how-do-i-set-a-thumbnail-when-playing-audio-in-ios-safari

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API).

Here is a sample code from MDN which describes the various methods of this API:

```
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: 'Unforgettable',
    artist: 'Nat King Cole',
    album: 'The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)',
    artwork: [
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
    ]
  });

  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('stop', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekto', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('skipad', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
}
```

Here is the same API referenced on Google Developers Web which highlights your use case. [Customize Media Notifications and Handle Playlists](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session)

Comment: Lol i was just about to post the same answer, lucky i decided to refresh the page and check!

Comment: @Kazi Raheeb: if this answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.